# Moving Photos between albums in Apple Photos app

Tags: apple

I'm using Photos Version 3.0 (3251.12.190) on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.
I have over 3,000 screenshots. I'd like to go through them and add them to albums (or some other way of categorizing the photos). I don't think you can move a photo from the Photos library or from the Screenshots album (which makes sense). I'd like to add all of the screenshots to an album (that represents all of the screenshots I want to categorize) and then move them to new albums. I can't find a way to move a photo - everything I try copies the photo from one album to another. The reason I want to move the photos is because I want to keep track of which photos I've categorized and which photos I haven't. Can anyone recommend a workflow that does this?

Comment: You can also try to ask on [Ask Different SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Cut  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>X</kbd>  then Paste  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>  same as in most apps.
I can't test Screenshots, but if they're treated like a 'library' rather than an 'album', then you could perhaps set up an intermediate album to keep track of progress. Copy all to there, then cut paste into their new album locations.

You can't  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  / drag, or Copy then opt/Paste  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd> , as you would in Finder, but regular cut/paste works fine between albums.